# __doPostBack is not triggering from external Js file

Tags: javascript, asp.net

When i tried to trigger  __doPostBack() manually from external Js file is not triggering.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#tabsids a").click(function () {    
        __doPostBack('<%= btntrigger.ClienID%>', '');
    });
 });
```

Comment: Do you include the file that contains the function?

Comment: While there is often advice to use __doPostBack in ASP.NET it is not good advice. _ in JavaScript usually means "private, do not touch". Guess what double underscore means :)

Comment: $('input[id$=btntrigger]').trigger('click'); worker for external js file.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to interpolate my angle bracket, percent, equals <%= %> syntax in external javascript files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/159842/is-it-possible-to-interpolate-my-angle-bracket-percent-equals-syntax-in)

Answer (score 1):

You need the **name attribute of the HTML element of the button you wish to click** as the first argument to __doPostBack(). HOw you will get that in your actual case is a different matter, but you cannot use server code blocks ()<%=%> outside of ASP context (i.e., outside of aspx, ascx files). Perhaps you can consider a partial ID selector with jQuery, something like

$("input[id$='btntrigger']").attr("name")

where input is the element type, so you may need to change it.

YOu can also simply try the click() method of the jQuery wrapper that you get, perhaps it will do the job.